# JFC unit test tutorial /example

Tags: java, unit-testing

PLease guide me to a nice jfcunit tutorial,

plz help me out how to use it, as i could not find more info on that,

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use another Unit testing framework for Swing applications?
JFC Unit hasn't been updated since 2004, and it looks quite abandoned, so there's no hope to get support or documentation for it.

We use mostly Marathon and [UISpec4J](http://www.uispec4j.org/), but there are many other tools that are good and not so "abandoned" like JFCUnit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but are they free

Comment: Yes, they are free. They are also open source, and what's more surprising(for open source projects), they also have good documentation :).